# route *local traffic* destined for 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.2.2

Tags: routes, iptables, private-subnet

I have a nonstandard network of VMs that are causing routing headaches.  Each VM is homed on on three different subnets (`192.168.1.0/24` through `192.168.3.0/24`), and each VM can connect to every other VM --- but only over a single subnet.  For example: VM1 (`192.168.*.1`) can connect to VM2 (`192.168.*.2`) only over subnet 2 (can ping `192.168.2.2`), while VM3 can connect to VM2 only over subnet 3 (can ping `192.168.3.2`).

I'd like to write some iptables rules (or similar) on VM1 such that I can have a "fake route" for local traffic to `192.168.1.2` which actually goes to `192.168.2.2`. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I can just ignore the subnet information and directly add a route via the correct ethernet device. Neat!

For example, if `ens2` has a route to `192.168.2.0/24`, I can just run `ip route add 192.168.1.2/32 dev ens2` and that will work correctly, assuming the device at the other end of `ens2` actually does have `192.168.1.2` as one of its addresses.